# Roy and Profile Picture

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with my code, i'm doing the code of Roy and Profile Picture in the hackearth, and when i going to run, this error appears:

'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'

This is my code:

```
l = int(input())
n = int(input())
i = 0
while i < n:
    wh = str(input().split('  '))
    w,h = int(wh[0]),int(wh[1])
    if w == l and h == l:
        print('ACCEPTED')
    else:
        if w > l and h > l:
            print('CROP IT')
        else:
            print('UPLOAD ANOTHER')

    i+=1
```

sorry for my mistakes with the english, i'm learning. Is this in python 3.x

Comment: Please, paste your input, or better replace `input()` with variables containing strings and paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Correct Program is below:

```
l = int(input())
n = int(input())
i = 0
while i < n:
    wh = (input().split())
    w = int(wh[0])
    h = int(wh[1])
    if w < l or h < l:
        print('UPLOAD ANOTHER')
    else:
        if w == h and (w >= l and h >= l) :
          print('ACCEPTED')  
        else:
            print('CROP IT')

    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int L = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        int N = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        int i = 0;
        while(i++ < N) {
            String[] arr = s.nextLine().split(" ");
            int W = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            int H = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            if(W < L || H < L) {
                System.out.println("UPLOAD ANOTHER");
            } else if (W >= L && H >= L) {
                if(W == H) {
                    System.out.println("ACCEPTED");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("CROP IT");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: First, I have taken the scanner object. Then, I have read the input and using the while loop, I found out the values that are present in each line. Then, I have used conditional statements to check the conditions that are mentioned in the question.